# SQLite Running Count Query

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have an SQLite table...

Installs

```
Id   Timestamp          City

1    2017-04-14 12:00   Lisbon
2    2017-04-15 02:00   York
3    2017-04-17 16:00   Perth
4    2017-04-17 18:00   Ohio
1    2017-04-18 22:00   Dundee
```

I need a query that gives me installs to date for each day...

```
Date            Installs To Date

2017-04-14      1
2017-04-15      2
2017-04-16      2   
2017-04-17      4
2017-04-18      5
```

Comment: So how far did you get? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why is there `2017-04-16`, but not `2017-04-19` in the output?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis not very far, all the examples I've found are using cross joins and summing numeric columns rather than counting dates.@CL there were no installs on the 16 so the running count remains the same as the previous day

Comment: This answer might help you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822077/292411

Comment: @C.Evenhuis The strftime function was useful but the query still only counts installs per month rather than total installs to date.

Comment: There are more options to that method, see https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html - try something like `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ...)`

Comment: Yes but whilst being useful to know they don't solve my problem